# Import MySQL database on Azure

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-sql-database

I need to move my Drupal website to Azure hosting. I have created web app on Azure then deployed Acquia Drupal 7 on MySQL. I used Kudu, installed phpMyAdmin and tried to import my database (100Mb), after 2-3 minutes I have got an error:

> 500 - The request timed out.
>
> The web server failed to respond within the specified time.

I have added `SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT: 3600` to my app settings, but I did not help.

Comment: Hi are you still facing the issue

Comment: No, the MS support, told me that it's impossible and I need to use command line instead phpMyAdmin.